# What is the words for the relationship between pounds and pence, or dollars and cents?

Tags: single-word-requests, grammatical-roles

A pound is a higher denomination than pence. I'm looking for the word that describes the relationship between a small denomination and a large one, or potentially between denominations in any direction.